# Best way to embed image coming from database in html view

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, database, image

I'm using `byte[]` symbols to store images data in a database like this:

```
ITEM_IMAGE VARBINARY(MAX),
```

And then when I retrieve the image and display it, I proceed like this:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64, @(Convert.ToBase64String(Model.mChildCard.NormalImage))" alt="@Model.mChildCard.mCardName" title="@Model.mChildCard.mCardName" class="nullify"/>
```

I do this because I cannot guarantee that our application will have write access on the server it will be deployed and, instead of storing the images in normal files (and there are a LOT of images, talking about 70k and more), we choose to store them in database and retrieve them as such.

Now I want to make sure this is the best way of handling those files in razor views as there may be a lot of images displayed at once. Will it have an impact on the speed it is rendered? What "weight" will have the database? Is there a better way to do things?

Comment: Having images in-line like this will potentially make the html huge & load very slowly on standard broadband speeds - this is very dependent on the size and quantity of images you have. An HTML size is generally < 100KB, so in-lining images makes it proportionally massive, and the browser will stall waiting for an image to download in-line before it renders the page. A better solution would be to have an Action Result you can pass a meaningful variable to retrieve the image byte array from the db, and present it to the client as a file (using return File(yourByeArray, "image/png");)

Comment: Hey, interesting! I'd love to try it out. Might you put this as an answer with an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To serve images:

Your new controller action:

```
public ActionResult GetImage(string imageID)
{
    byte[] imgArray;
    //call your db and get your byte array.

    if(imgArray != null)
    {
        return File(imageArray, "image/png");
    }
    else
    {
        throw new HttpException(404);
    }

}
```

Add a route:

```
routes.MapRoute("Images", "images/{imageId}", New With {.controller = "yourImageController", .action = "GetImage")
```

And from your HTML:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "YourImageController", new{ @imageId=Model.mChildCard.imageId})" alt="@Model.mChildCard.mCardName" title="@Model.mChildCard.mCardName" class="nullify"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public FileStreamResult GetDBImage(string imageId)
{
  using (var conn = GetConnection())
  {
    conn.Open();
    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand)
    {
      cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ITEM_IMAGE FROM ... WHERE id=@id";
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", imageId);
      using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        return File(rdr.GetStream(0), "image/png")
    }
  }  
}
```

Also, consider using async.

Comment: How could I make it async? I don't know how to do it, and I'd love to dig in that.

Comment: Return Task<T> from action and use async version of GetStream(). But dont't forget about managing DB connection lifetime (use Task.ContinueWith() or await in C#5+ to close it).